Excel takes a long time to open my file
it is approx 5 minutes to open similar (lil bit complex) files. but when i open  it in my friend laptop it just open instantly (in secs). there must be something wrong with my microsoft excel.
Actually it happened once before, then i clean uninstall (cache, registry,etc) micorosft office files and reinstall it again and the problem is gone. but after few days , it comes again.

To test if it's the Excel installation on your PC, install LibreOffice and open it in Calc. If that's just as slow, so is your PC. If it's fast, reinstall latest Excel, or keep using Calc.

Is is the exact same file that opens slowly for you and quickly for your friend? As in, can you send the same file as an email attachment to them and you, and both of you open that attachment, and you observe the same behavior? Use the Open and Repair function in Excel on the file to see if there's issues with it. What are you computer specs and details? Use Process Explorer to watch your computer opening this file, and see if there are anything indications what might be the problem. Is the file looking for some dependency and timing out? How complex is this file?
